# How to process XML files using Rapidminer for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, rapidminer

I am new to Rapidminer. I have many XML files and I want to classify these files manually based on keywords. Then I would like to train a classifier like Naive Bayer and SVM on these data and calculate their performances using cross- validator.

Could you please let me know different steps for this?

Should I need to use text processing activities like  tokenising, TFIDF etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The steps would go something like this

1. Loop over files - i.e. iterate over all files in a folder and read each one in turn.
2. For each file

   - read it in as a document.
   - tokenize it using operators like `Extract Information` or `Cut Document` containing suitable XPath queries to output a row corresponding to the extracted information in the document.
3. Create a document vector with all the rows. This is where TF-IDF or other approaches would be used. The choice depends on the problem at hand with TF-IDF being a usual choice where it is important to give more weight to tokens that appear often in a relatively small number of the documents.
4. Build the model and use cross validation to get an estimate of the performance on unseen data.

I have included a [link](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/finding-processes-in-repository.html) to a process that you could use as the basis for this. It reads the RapidMiner repository which contains XML files so is a good example of processing XML documents using text processing techniques. Obviously, you would have to make some large modifications for your case.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is too late to reply. But it could help to other people. There is an extension called 'text mining extension', I am using version 6.1.0 . So you may go to RapidMiner > help>update and install this extension. It will get all the files from one directory. It has various text mining algorithms that you may use

Also, I found this tutorial video which could be of some help to you as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXrUz5CWM4E